# Mysql tables into one table

Tags: mysql, mysql5

```
CREATE TABLE emp_u (
        id      INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        emailAddress    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        username        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        passwd          VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        title           CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
        firstName       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        surname         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE KEY(emailAddress),
        UNIQUE KEY(username),
        KEY idx_fullname (firstName, surname)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE emp_u_p (
    employer_id_fk  INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    s_mgt           TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    add_j_mgt       TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    edit_j_mgt      TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    del_j_mgt       TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    j_mgt           TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default 0,
    cp_mgt  TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default 0,
    ph_mgt      TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default 0,
    cb_mgt      TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default 0,
    search_mgt      TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (employer_id_fk)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have these two tables in my database. Will be better to combine these two tables together or leave then as it is.

I'm new to database and just write some tables for my mysql.

Comment: What will you use these tables for? Is `emp` is short for `employee`?

Comment: are the primary keys the same in both? if yes you can merge them

Comment: They will be used for employer to log on to system and set them for different permission

Comment: Can you (just for our benefit) change all of the obscure names to semantic names? i.e. change emp_u_id to employee_user_id or something?

Comment: yes the primary key for both tales is same because they will be only one record for each employer i dont need to create a another id record

Comment: I guess the second one is permissions?

Comment: @ ctrahey yes its a persmission table for employer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are advising toward normalization (always!), then I suggest you leave them as two tables, but change the nature of the permissions table to be a one-to-many instead of 1-1 like it appears to be now.

There should be one row for each employee in the employee table, and then one row *per permission* in the permissions table.

```
CREATE TABLE emp_u_p (
 emp_u_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 permission_name varchar
);
```

This is highly advantageous when you need to add permission types to your system; you will not need to refactor your schema. If you want to really go all the way, make a third table called "permissions", and then have a many-to-many, where your employee_permissions table is just two foreign keys: one for employee_id and one for permission_id

To select employees with a given permission:

```
SELECT emp_u.* 
FROM emp_u JOIN emp_u_p 
  ON emp_u.id = emp_u_p.emp_u_id 
  AND permission_name = "add_j_mgt";
```

Comment: so leave the tables as it is and just enter same data into these feilds e.g. 1, add_j_mgt, '1'

Comment: Well, kinda. The structure of your second table would change (to the DDL I showed here), and then yes, there would be 1 row PER permission in it.

Comment: I modified it a bit, since you do not need the enabled bit for this relationship... simply the existence of the row indicates that the permission is enabled (delete the row to remove the permission)

Comment: OK because I have same layout for my admin table i should then create one table and called it as permission and have they coulmn id, permission_name, who_is_user

Answer (score 0):

As your tables represent, first table conatin the basic info of employee and second one contains the permission right of that employee...I think, there should be relationship between two table  as `foreign relationship`...you can use ID of employee as a `foreign key` in second table...It'll maintain the database property.....So, I would recommend you to use two table with `foreign relationship`......

Comment: It should be noted that MyISAM does not support these constraints (which can be okay of your code handles it). You should use InnoDB to get MySQL to enforce relationships for you.

Comment: I already have a foreign key employer_id_fk is my key in emp_u_p table

Comment: @ctrahey thats right because i'm using MyISAM i can't enter constraints between each table

Comment: I assume, OP is working on MySQL 5.5 in which Innodb is the default storage engine .....

Comment: I'm forcing my database to be set as ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Oh sorry...I just read the column name of the table and answer according to tag made.....